# What do these views do?

Tags: java, hibernate, jackson, dropwizard

I am studying a dropwizard project which contains, in its views package, a series of classes like the following:

```
package api.views;

public class FooView {

    public static class FindAll {
    }

    public static class Item {
    }

}
```

The only place where I noticed such views to be used is in the resource classes, in a way similar to the following:

```
@GET
@Timed
@UnitOfWork
@JsonView(FooView.FindAll.class)
public Response getAll() {
     //connects to the DB via hibernate
     //returns a Response containing a JSON list of Foos in the DB
}
```

I don't understand the role of such views as they are empty static classes and if they can modify the returned JSON.

Answer (score 0):

`@JsonView` annotation is part of Jackson features. I haven't used this feature but the documentation states the following:

> "Views" in this context mean ability to define subsets of logical properties (things accessed via getters or fields) to serialize. Views are defined statically (using annotations), but view to use for serialization is chosen dynamically (per serialization).

Source: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews
For the `@JsonView` description check "Views with JAX-RS" almost at the end of the webpage.